# getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path) always return null, even when the path is correct

Tags: java

I am using Java project to do this not a dynamic web project and I just placed my *.wav* file to directly project(on project name right click n paste).

I tried to read many posts but of no use. help me on this. I tried to read many posts but of no use.

```
try{
      // Open an audio input stream.
      URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Rain.wav");
      System.out.println("url:"+url);
      AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
      // Get a sound clip resource.
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
      clip.open(audioIn);
      clip.start();
      /* clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);  */
 } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Please read the javadoc of `getResource` then learn how to setup your classpath correctly in your IDE of choice.

Comment: Your project directory is probably not in your classpath! You should put such a file in your resources directory (and beware that you are doing a relative lookup here -- an absolute one is preferred for reliable results; what if your class changes package?)

Answer (score 2):

> getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path) always return null, even when the path is correct

No it doesn't.

> I just placed my .wav file to directly project

Exactly. That's the wrong place. Your path isn't correct. Your `Rain.wav` file needs to be in the root directory of your JAR file the way you're looking for it. The root of the project has precisely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Load file from Spring Boot JAR**

If you would like to load a file from classpath in a Spring Boot JAR, then you have to use the resource.getInputStream() method to retrieve it as a InputStream. If you try to use resource.getFile() you will receive an error, because Spring tries to access a file system path, but it can not access a path in your JAR.

`Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");
InputStream dbAsStream = resource.getInputStream()`

[blog] : https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/